# How to track Google Analytics/ Adwords Conversions in VueJS

Tags: google-analytics, vue.js, google-ads-api, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm having a VueJS application where a user submits a form. Data is sent to the server using Vue-resource. I need to tell Google that this is a conversion.

What Google gives me is a script where told me to put in 'thanks.html' or some page like that. My VueJS application is a single page application. So what should I do? Where should I put the code?

**VueJS code for submitting the form:**

```
methods: {
  submit() {
    this.$http.post(store.state.url+'api/submit_quote.php', {
        formData: this.formData
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.submitted = true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: can you pass a route on your single page app to the google script? example: `www.mysite.com` is your SPA and you pass on `www.mysite.com/thanks` to the google script?

Comment: I can do that. But it's a little time consuming to do at this moment! That's why. But what if I can do that? Where can I put that code?

Comment: Share the code you receive from google as well, then I can add the answer, setting up a router is pretty simple. It shouldn't take much time.

Comment: You should be able to include the right google code into your vue function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a google analytics tracking event inside the .then as:

```
  methods: {
  submit() {
    this.$http.post(store.state.url+'api/submit_quote.php', {
        formData: this.formData
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.submitted = true
      ga('send', 'event', 'some-goal', 'success');
    });
  }
}
```

You can then set up a goal in Google Analytics for the event, this goal can then be shared back to AdWords.

For more details see: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Comment: I think that will also work. What I did use is goog_report_conversion('https://www.quotzap.com/get-quote') and its working!! (It's for AdWords conversion tracking)